# datagridview Link cellcontent click not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using this code to make my column(fetched from database in dataTable) as linkcolumn

**edit:**

```
void show_visits()
    {
        try
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sonorepo.mdb");
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + err);
        }
        this.pid = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetPatientID(cmbPatientName.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select Patient_ID,VisitNo,VisitDate,remark from Patient_Visit_Details WHERE Patient_ID=" + pid, con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
        adp1.Fill(dt);
        this.dataGridViewVisits.DataSource = dt;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewVisits.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            linkCell.Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
            row.Cells[2] = linkCell;
        }
        this.dataGridViewVisits.CellContentClick+=new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.CellContentClick);

    }
```

and I am using below code to open form when i click on any link(content link) of this column ,but event is not getting triggered ,where I am doing mistake ?

```
 private void CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && ((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewLinkColumn))
     {
         int pid = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewVisits.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Patient_ID"].Value);
         ViewR viewrepofrm = new ViewR(pid);
         viewrepofrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
         viewrepofrm.Show();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where is the error or the output?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas I am not getting any error ,simply when I am clicking on cell content link the `ViewR` form is not getting displayed,which should be displayed as per needed

Comment: is CellContentClick actually being call as defined in the event?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas yes it is being called ,but not going within if loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the column is set when adding it to the `DataGridView`. I understand that you are adding columns by relying on the default type (`TextBoxColumn`) and this is not changed in your first code (you are converting cells into `DataGridViewLinkCell`, not columns). Thus, your code should work with the following modification:

```
private void CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && ((DataGridView)sender)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewLinkCell))
    {
         int pid = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewVisits.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Patient_ID"].Value);
         ViewR viewrepofrm = new ViewR(pid);
         viewrepofrm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
         viewrepofrm.Show();
    }
}
```

In any case, bear in mind that the kind of cell-type modification you are doing is not 100% save in all the situations. If you are populating the `DataGridView` from a `DataSource` and you perform the cell type change just once, it is OK (quickest/easiest option); in any other situation (where you have to add the columns manually), you should better set the type for the given column (`DataGridViewLinkColumn` in this case) at the start, when adding the column.

Comment: Yes its working now ,I have shown my full code ,am I adding linkcells to right positions now ,as u said,as I am fetching data in datatable so I did it like this

Comment: yes problem is solved ,I just want to know am i doing it in right way ,as u said so this question raised in my mind

Comment: @Durga Ah OK. Please, update your answer with your code (the part where the columns are added) and I can advise you. If you are adding them via DataSource or equivalent, you would have to change the Column type afterwards. Write down your code and I can take a look at it.

Comment: @Durga Yes. DataSource... If you are performing the cells type change just once, at this point, there shouldn't any problem to rely on this approach (actually, it might be the simpler one). I wasn't sure that's why I mentioned this issue in my answer. I will update it right now: on this specific context (DataSource + type change only one) is OK.